# Post constructor initialization

Tags: c++

I have a set of objects derived from common base, `ApiObject`. I need to be able to register all ApiObjects in a separate data structure, but I need to have an actual address of the object being created, not the base class (I'm using multiple inheritance).

I can't put the code to register an object in `ApiObject` constructor, because it does not know the address of the derived object; nor can I put it in the derived classes' constructors, because we have no way of knowing whether we are actually constructing another derived class (e.g. if class `B` is inherited from `A`, and both can be constructed).

So the only option I see is to explicitly call the registration function every time we create an object, as in

```
B* b = new B(...);
RegisterObject(b);
```

However, this doesn't seem to be a very good solution, as I have to remember to call this function every time.

I suppose I should give more context to explain why I'm doing this. The objects are created via an overloaded new operator, and it needs the object to know the context it was created in (Lua state). E.g.

```
Foo* object = new(L) Foo(...);
// Foo is derived from ApiObject, and we want ApiObject to have a reference to L
```

Currently it is done in a somewhat unelegant way - the new operator allocates additional bytes before the object and stores the L pointer in there, along with some additional data to describe the object type. The base class then receives a pointer to this 'metadata' via the init function.
Otherwise, the first thing that comes to mind are virtual functions, but they can't be called from the constructor, so I'd have to register the base `ApiObject` pointer but only call the virtual function at some later point, and I'm not sure that's prettier than my current implementation.

Comment: What do you want to do with the actual address?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg "this is the same in both the derived and in the base object" --- no, not really.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg This will _not_ be the same physical address in the base class and the derived class.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg try multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

What is the type required for `RegisterObject`?  If it takes a
`Base*`, then you can call it from the constructor of `Base`,
regardless of the final hierarchy.  If it takes some other type,
then you want to call it from the constructor of that type; you
do *not* want to call it from all classes derived from `Base`,
but only for those derived from whatever type it takes.

If `RegisterObject` takes a `Base*`, and you call it from a
function in a derived class, the first thing that will occur is
that the pointer you pass it will be converted to a `Base*`.
`RegisterObject` never receives a pointer to the derived object,
only to the `Base` in the derived object.

Answer (score 0):

You can additionaly derieve every object you want to register from CRTP class, which performs registration, e.g.

```
template<class T>
struct registarar_t<T>
{
  registarar_t()
  {
     register(derived());
  }

  T* derieved()
  {
    return static_cast<T*>(this);
  }
}

struct IWantToRegister : registrar_t<IWantToRegister>, ApiObject
{
}
```

Also, **be careful**, `derived()` pointer is right, but object is not yet initialized (accessing it in parent constructor)

Comment: Technically, the `static_cast` is undefined behavior (although I can't imagine it failing).  It's also illegal if the base class is virtual (which will often be the case where multiple inheritance is involved).

Comment: @JamesKanze Why is it undefined?

Comment: In this case, the only answer I can give is "because the
standard says so".  In the absence of virtual derivation, I
can't see any reason why it can't trivially be made to work.
And if there is virtual derivation, the `static_cast` is
illegal.  But §3.8/5 explicitly says that it is undefined
behavior.

Comment: @JamesKanze but I meant final classes, which won't be bases for others. Will it be illegal that case?

Comment: @JamesKanze: If my understanding is correct, 3.8 defers to 12.7 for objects under construction/destruction, and is only applicable otherwise. 12.7 only says that `dynamic_cast` is undefined in certain cases.

Comment: @n.m. In the cases covered by §12.7, §12.7 has precedence.  But
§12.7 only covers conversions from derived to base; the
conversion in question is from base to derived (which will only
be valid once the constructor of derived has started).

Comment: @kassak `registrar_t` is a base of `IWantToRegister` and will try to convert its `this` to type `IWantToRegister` before the constructor of `IWantToRegister` has started.  That's (formally) undefined behavior.  (In practice, I've had cases where the conversions didn't work as expected, but only when virtual bases were involved.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Yep, for virtual inheritance static upcasting won't work. But I guess there is funny misunderstanding between us, based on the fact that `I` at the class name does not mean interface, but came here from my attempt to make example self readable (struct-i-want-to-register) :D Sorry =)

Comment: @kassak According to the standard, even non-virtual is undefined behavior.  Whether it's worth worrying about, I don't know; as I said, I can't imagine an implementation where it would fail.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe kassak's solution is more elegant, I'm not that advanced, but I'd recommend something like this (register shoudl be called in the constructor so you don't have to write it every time:

```
#include <iostream>
struct ApiObject;
void registerObj(ApiObject *foo);

struct ApiObject{
    public:
        ApiObject(std::string n){
            name = n;
            registerObj(this);
        }

        std::string name;
};

void registerObj(ApiObject *foo){
    std::cout<<"register called on "<<foo->name<<"\n";
}


struct A : public ApiObject{
    public:
        A(std::string n) : ApiObject(n) {
            std::cout<<"init A\n";
        }
};

struct B : public ApiObject{
    public:
    B(std::string n) : ApiObject(n) {
        std::cout<<"init B\n";
    }
};


int main(){
    B *b = new B("b obj");
    A *a = new A("a obj");

    delete b;
    delete a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the registration function from the base constructor. Just make the base destructor virtual. The address will be same for base and derived class. Just don't use the pointer address before the whole object is created.

Once all the objects are fully created, the pointer address can be safely used through virtual functions or dynamic-casted to derived class.